# Xcode not recognizing already defined sprite?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm making a simple iOS game where the goal is to get the angel in the middle of the screen to shoot arrows at monsters coming at him from all sides. But when I try to calculate the direction of the arrow being shot, Xcode says that the "angel" sprite doesn't exist, even though I've already used it. Here's my code:

```
#import "MyScene.h"

static inline CGPoint rwAdd(CGPoint a, CGPoint b)
{
    return CGPointMake(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}
static inline CGPoint rwSub(CGPoint a, CGPoint b)
{
    return CGPointMake(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
}
static inline CGPoint rwMult(CGPoint a, float b)
{
    return CGPointMake(a.x * b, a.y * b);
}
static inline float rwLength(CGPoint a)
{
    return sqrtf(a.x * a.x + a.y * a.y);
}
static inline CGPoint rwNormalize(CGPoint a)
{
    float length = rwLength(a);
    return CGPointMake(a.x / length, a.y / length);
}

@implementation MyScene

- (id) initWithSize: (CGSize) size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed: 1.0 green: 1.0 blue: 1.0 alpha: 1.0];

        SKSpriteNode *angel = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: @"Angel"];
        angel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        angel.xScale = 0.25;
        angel.yScale = 0.25;
        [self addChild: angel];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode: self];

    SKSpriteNode *arrow = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Arrow"];
    projectile.position = self.angel.position;

    CGPoint offset = rwSub(location, arrow.position);
    [self addChild: arrow];
    CGPoint direction = rwNormalize(offset);
    CGPoint shootAmount = rwMult(direction, 500);
    CGPoint realDest = rwAdd(shootAmount, arrow.position);
    float velocity = 480.0/1.0;
    float realMoveDuration = self.size.width / velocity;
    SKAction *actionMove = [SKAction moveTo: realDest duration: realMoveDuration];
    SKAction *actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [arrow runAction: [SKAction sequence: @[actionMove, actionMoveDone]]];

}

@end
```

When I'm defining "arrow.position = self.angel.position", Xcode doesn't recognize "angel" as a sprite. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is out of scope. You are setting it as a child  so you must retrieve it in the other touchesEnded: method you will need to do the following:

`SKSpriteNode *angel = [self childNodeWithName:@"Angel"];`